# Rails - I want to have some type of automated testing - for LIBs, and Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What do I need to learn, where should I go learn it. And why is your recommendation the way to go.
My app has your standard forms, like signin, reset password etc...

The app also has an email ingest library which I want to write automated tests for.

Where should I start? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of testing frameworks for Ruby and/or Rails: [RSpec](http://relishapp.com/rspec), [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/), [TestUnit](http://test-unit.rubyforge.org/), [MiniTest](https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest), [Shoulda](http://thoughtbot.com/community/) to name but a few.  I would recommend trying them out and finding one that best suits your needs.  It usually comes down to a personal preference.  No framework is always better than another.  I have found that some of my projects actually work best when I write tests using a couple of these frameworks depending on what I actually want to test.

As for testing email functionality, I would recommend picking a testing framework, say TestUnit (which is built into Ruby) and going with it.  One thing I would make sure to do is to write tests that don't rely on your code actually receiving emails.  That way you are testing your implementation and not whether or not emails are actually being sent or received.  For example, you could use mocks and stubs to fake actual email data and actual email interactions.  You could also write a test class that mimicks an email interface for receiving and sending emails and test that your code can interact with that.  Whenever possible try to test only your implementation and not external dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Pan, I'm very interested in writing a test for my email ingest that uses a lib 'class MailingJob < Struct.new(:mailing_id)' What's the best way to go about testing that type of object? thanks